# What the name of the knot that is used for tying something to a pole?

Tags: knots, knot-identification

Whats are some simple knots to attach a rope to a pole?

It involves simply looping around the pole, and then running through one of the ends through the loop and tightening

Comment: This really needs a picture

Comment: Sounds like an overhand knot based in the description but that's not a very good way to tie something to a pole. A picture would help.

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear since there isn't a picture.

Comment: Qudit got it. I couldn't post a picture because I didn't know the name so I don't know how to google an image.

Comment: ParoX you can take a picture of the knot you mean. If it is an overhand know, as Qudit says, that is **not** a good not for this.

Comment: Wasnt asking for a recommended knot, I was just trying to understand what the most common knot was called. I was researching knots and didnt know what the overhand knot was called.

Comment: You can use a clove hitch, lark's head, two-half hitches, taughtline hitch, and timber hitch.  Those are basic hitches, and of course, there are many others - not so basic.

Answer (score 5):

A [hitch knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hitch_knots).

> A hitch is a type of knot used for binding rope to an object.

You may be thinking of a clove hitch.

Comment: I'll second the clove hitch.

Comment: Majority of the time this is the clove hitch, so yea. I'd vote for that one.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it might be a [bowline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowline)?

[image]